# is it possible to load existing href links with jquery into a div tag without reloading?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't really understand how ajax works, but I have seen tutorials that allow me to change a `div` to a web page by clicking on a button.

Is there a way to load the clicked link into the `div` tag without refreshing, by reading the attributes within the `<a>` tag?

I have the following HTML:

```
<table align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='http://libraryofalexandria.tk/index.php'>Home</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='http://libraryofalexandria.tk/pdfupload.php'>Book Upload</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='http://libraryofalexandria.tk/booksearch.php'>Book search</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id='pageLoad'></div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to do that.

It would be something like this:

```
// Catch the click on your a tag
$("a").click(function(){
    // Load the content of the page referenced in the a-tags href
    $("#pageLoad").load($(this).attr("href"));
    // Prevent browsers default behavior to follow the link when clicked
    return false;
});
```

It is worth to note that accessing data from other domains are restricted by the same origin policy. From the jQuery documentation of `.load()`:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

If that is the case, you might have to look into [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: you have no idea how much this really helped. thank you a million times over

Answer (score 3):

You can attach a click event to the links and using [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), load the content into the div.

```
$("a").click(function() {        
    $("#pageLoad").load(this.href);

    return false;
});​
```

This will only work though if the links are  on the same domain due to cross-domain security restrictions. See the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) documentation for more details.

Comment: 'event.preventDefault();' and 'return false;' make same things, why you use both of them? No need to wrap DOM element with jquery object, you can just use 'this.href'.

Comment: @webdeveloper: this.href does make sense indeed. You are correct there is no need to add the overhead, wrapping the DOM reference. Regarding `event.preventDefault` you are probably right. A colleague of mine mentioned that in some browsers/scenarios he found that he needed to do that or the click event still executed the default behaviour before the code completed execution and `return false;` was reached. Adding it by default doesn't seem to harm but prevented the odd exceptional behaviour.

Comment: very interesting, please, ask him about browsers and versions when you will have ability.

Comment: @webdeveloper: Will do and I post the result. If it is something I can't replicate in a fiddle I let you know anyway.

Comment: @webdeveloper: Apologies for not getting back on this, I completely forgot. I never found out why this was suggested to me in the past but it might have been related to multiple events bound to the same link interfering with each other. As this is something I couldn't replicate though and does sound very edge-case like I updated the answer to be more up-to-date, including your comment on `this.href`. Makes sense to not have the unnecessary overhead to wrap jQuery around a native property call when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to cook an egg but it sounds like you would find jQuery's Load useful in this case:

http://api.jquery.com/load/